# What is the hex code for the jumbotron grey colour?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, colors

What is the hex code for the jumbotron grey colour?

Google says `#42ba96` which is not right, and I tried `"grey"` which is too dark. Which is the correct hex code?

Comment: Do you mean the default background color? #eeeeee

Comment: @AHaworth Yep the default grey color it uses. I think it's `#E9ECEF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are using Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4

```
/* bootstrap 3 */
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/* bootstrap 4 */
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a chrome addon called colorzilla and it tells me it's `#E9ECEF`. It looks right but others may be able to advise